# How to implement a voice recognizer in android- "Recognizer not present"?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I have not installed Google voice search in my android phone. I can not install it because it only available for US. But vilingo app woks well on my android phone. In my own voice recognition app it says "Recognizer not present".

this is the code i'm using from the android developer site.

```
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            intent, pm.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (activities.size() == 0)
    {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }
```

why it returns empty list from above code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i download voice search and installed it. :) not it is working

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html it also depends on what android version and device model you are using on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i downloaded voice search and installed it. :) now it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
I think Update Your Devise Os , 


later try this link 


http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-basics-19-string-array-and.html
```